# Twilio CallResource.Create Does Not Compile When Specifying A Twiml Parameter - C#

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

Trying to follow the Call Resource API & code examples listed [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource).

The code example given to make an outbound call is specifying twiml in the request -

```
var call = CallResource.Create(
    twiml: new Twilio.Types.Twiml("<Response><Say>Ahoy there!</Say></Response>"),
    to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+15558675310"),
    from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+15552223214")
);
```

When I try this, Visual Studio gives an error and doesn't allow me to compile -

> The best overload for 'Create' does not contain a parameter named
> 'twiml'

Am I missing something, or is the API documentation wrong / outdated?

Comment: Make sure you installed the right package - I tried it and there's no error on my end

Comment: This worked for me on Twilio library version `6.2.0` with .NET 7. What version of the library are you using?

Comment: Looks like I was using version 5.78.0. I'm on 6.2.0 now and it works just fine. Thank you both.

Comment: @Brady I'm closing the loop on this by submitting it as an answer. Glad you resolved your issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `twiml` optional parameter was introduced in [version **5.36.0**](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/blob/5.37.0/CHANGES.md#2019-12-04-version-5360). According to git source history, it should also be in **5.78.0**, so not sure why it was missing for you. Maybe it was using an even older version for some reason. Either way, upgrading to the latest version the the `Twilio` library should solve the problem.